# Hamiltonian for vector quantities in curved spacetimes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, classical-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-field-theory

How would we define the Hamiltonian of some Lagrangian in a curved background (with a timelike killing vector such that time is defined)?

**My reasoning would be the following:**

$$S = \int d^dx \sqrt{-g} \mathcal{L}[A,\nabla_\mu A_\nu]$$

such that

$$\delta S = \int d^dx \left( \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\nu} - \nabla_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \nabla_\mu A_\nu} \right)\delta A_\nu$$

which does indeed give us the Euler Lagrange equation: $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\nu} - \nabla_\mu\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \nabla_\mu A_\nu}=0$$

Notice how I had to use $\nabla A$ instead of $\partial A$ to be able to perform the partial integration in obtaining this result.

I would than define $$\Pi^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \nabla_\mu A_\nu}$$ such that the Euler Lagrange equation becomes: $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial A_\nu} - \nabla_\mu\Pi^{\mu\nu}=0.$$

It is here that I diverge from the literature that seems to use $\Pi^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}$ for some reason that I cannot understand.

This other definition of the conjugate momentum than affects the Hamiltonian in the sense that it is defined to be:

$$\mathcal{H} = \Pi^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu A_\nu - \mathcal{L}$$

**My question is:**

What is the correct definition of the conjugate momentum and with it the Hamiltonian.

And on a related note, how does the Hamiltonian describe time evolution in such a system, do we get $\partial_t A_\nu = E A_\nu$ or $\nabla_t A_\nu = E A_\nu$.

Comment: perhaps: if $\mathcal L$ is gauge-invariant, then it depends on $F=\mathrm dA$, i.e., it depends on $\nabla_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}=\partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}$. Therefore, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\nabla_\mu A_\nu)}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Why is it that $\nabla_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}=\partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}$?

Comment: @coconut because the $\Gamma$ parts cancel, inasmuch as $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric in $\mu\nu$ (assuming the connection to be torsion-free).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform

Indeed the two definitions are identical if we choose not to fix any gauge. But in practice we add a gauge fixing term $(\nabla A)^2$ such that they are no longer equivalent.

Than the whole question on which definition is correct is once again needed. 

Also, this still doesn't solve the question on which derivative to choose to depict time evolution.